# Is there a way to retrieve hexadecimal methodID from function ABI?

Tags: javascript, ethers.js

I am making a simple decompiler but i'm struggling with encoding my functions to signatures. For instance I have function `"transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount)"` which I want to encode into a 4 byte signature also known as MethodID, which for transfer is `0xa9059cbb`. Is there a way to do it? I'm using **ethers.js**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `ethers.utils.id` function.

```js
const { utils } = require('ethers')

console.log(utils.id('transfer(address,uint256)').substring(0, 10))
```

The `utils.id` function will return the keccak256 hash of the function signature you passed it. The `substring` function call is used to extract `0x` + first four bytes. So the final data is the method ID you're looking for.

https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/utils/hashing/#utils-id

Answer (score 2):

```js
const iface = new ethers.utils.Interface(abi)
const selector = iface.getSighash('transfer')
```

You can also get the interface from the `Contract` object: `const iface = contract.interface`.

If there is ambiguity in the function, then you'll have to add the parameters for `getSighash`: `const selector = iface.getSighash('transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount)')`, ethers will find the correct function for you.

Answer (score 1):

In ethers v6:

```js
  const selector = ethers.FunctionFragment.getSelector('mint', ['address', 'uint256']) // '0x40c10f19'
```

You don't need the ABI to get a function selector.